# Simultaneous keystrokes - emulating mouse movements with keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout, mouse, xkb, xmodmap, keyboard-event

I'm trying to emulate mouse movements and actions with keyboard, and I succeeded in remapping everything (e.g.: <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> to movements), with `xkb` (in particular using `xkbset -m`) and `xmodmap`.

The problem is that buttons are usually pressed one at a time, while I expect to be able to move simultaneously left and up with the mouse.

With `xmodmap` only seems not to be possible (at the end is only remapping one key on another key), so how can I do in order to move left-up while I am holding <kbd>h</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd> simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that much (almost nothing) about xmodmap, so I have no direct answer, but I have a few suggestions:

- map **SHIFT** and a key to do this
- use **yu,bn** for diagonals (<^y >^u Vn)
- try a different program:

  - [**xdotool**](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool)[(1)](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/xdotool.1) has limited mouse movement and good keyboard emulation
  - [**keynav**](https://github.com/jordansissel/keynav)[(1)](http://manpages.org/keynav) is a program that could solve your problems completely

Comment: You might already have xdotool, and it is included as part of and used by keynav.

Comment: both are pretty customizeable

Comment: Thank you, I already map the diagonal movements, but it is uncomfortable and a little bit unnatural, since when I start pressing down and then right I don’t expect to have to remember that instead I should start pressing something else (it’s not my use case but imagine to do it inside a game when you are controlling a character)

Comment: On the other end I already tried with keynav and it’s interesting, but currently it’s not the style I desire, since ai would like to be closer to a mouse, rather than completely alternative, and I saw xdotool but I didn’t figure out how to use it for solving simultaneity issue